# Magento: no order history for customers under "My Account" - orders object not being passed correctly

Tags: php, magento

I'm running Magento Enterprise 1.9, and customers are not seeing any orders in the "Order History" section of My Account. I have debugged this a lot and just can't figure out what's going on. Strangely, on our staging server, it works properly.

What I've done so far:

1) Ensured that `<visible_on_front/>` is applied to every order state within `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml` (so they should all be visible).

2) `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Block\Order\History.php`[(view file source)](http://paste2.org/p/2505946) grabs the orders from the database and sets them for the template file using `$this->setOrders($orders);` . I have debugged this object and output the raw SQL to get this:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*
FROM   `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table`
WHERE  ( main_table.customer_id = '4' )
       AND ( state IN ( 'new', 'processing', 'complete', 'closed',
                        'canceled', 'holded', 'payment_review' ) )
```

This *does* return orders for my test customer, on both staging and live servers.

3) `app\design\frontend\enterprise\astleyclarke\template\sales\order\history.phtml`[(view file source)](http://paste2.org/p/2505975) is the corresponding template file responsible for outputting the orders. It grabs the orders using `$_orders = $this->getOrders();` and checks it using `if($_orders->getSize()):`. **It is at this point that things go wrong.** The reported size is 0 on the live server, although it was not on the staging server despite both servers reporting orders in the database when I ran the SQL manually.

So to me it seems that the $orders object is not being passed or fetched correctly by the phtml file on the live server.

Any other ideas or help are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The order collection is initialized in `Mage_Sales_Block_Order_History::__construct`.

But the collection is not yet loaded.

What you can to do debug this, you can temporarily add an `$orders->load()` in the above function and then check the `_items` property of the `$order` object. Are there orders listed?

You can extract the select that was used by `(string) $order->getSelect()`.

If you get orders in this case, it might be possible that the collection is manipulated between the block `_construct` and the rendering of the view.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I think the OP ran into following scenario.
There is an extension installed that redefines the template phtml for the order history. The xml configuration points to a template file that is installed under `base/default` but the server uses a theme called `enterprise/astleyclarke`, the template file is therefore not reachable and there will be no output in that case, nor a log output.

Search in xml files after `history.phtml` from the app-folder and beyond. There's a big chance there is a config file that points to a location that doesn't exist under the active theme.

I ran into the same problem recently, an extension xml installed under `base/default/layout/chipmaster/reant.xml` had the following:

```
<template>chipmaster/reant/sales/order/history.phtml</template>
```

But the server is using the theme `xyz/default` and the history file from the config was hidden in:

```
design/frontend/base/default/template/chipmaster/reant/sales/order/history.phtml
```

To make the server print the history again, either move the file and its directory structure in to your theme, or edit the xml file. I did the later and after an edit to

```
<template>sales/order/history.phtml</template>
```

which is the default location, we had the order history in the frontend again.